# How i can save a value in real mode and access it in protected?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, protected

i got a code that that try to pass the VBE LFB address to the protected mode, but can't access the right value, i just dont know the right way to get a real mode saved value in the protected mode
(i think theres no problem here) the boot.s:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

setup_stack:

    xor ax, ax;                     // ax = 0
    mov ds, ax;                     // ds = 0

    mov es, ax;                     // es = ds
    mov bx, 0x8000;                 // stack segment can be any usable memory

    mov ss, bx;                     // stack start 0x80000
    mov sp, ax;                     // stack final 0x8FFFF

    cld;                            // clear direction flag

read_kernel:

    mov ah, 00;                     // reset disk
    int 13h;                        // disk interrupt

    mov ax, 0x0000;                 // register ax [0000]:1000
    mov bx, 0x1000;                 // register bx  0000:[1000]

    mov ah, 0x2;                    // read sector instruction
    mov al, 0x3;                    // sectors to read
    mov ch, 0x0;                    // cylinder
    mov cl, 0x2;                    // local to write
    mov dh, 0x0;                    // head

    int 0x13;                       // call the disk interupter

    jmp 0x0000:0x1000;              // Jump to kernel

    cli;                            // clear interrupt flag
    hlt;                            // halt
```

the kernel loads the VBE and after this, the protected mode, kernel.s:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x1000]

jmp main_x16;

%include "sys/x16/data.s";          // the GDT table
%include "sys/x16/code/VBE.s"       // 512+256 bytes so dont fit the boorloader

main_x16:

    call VBE.enable;                // its works and here i draw a pixel
    call enter_x32;                 // enter in protected mode ( x32 bits )

enter_x32:

    cli;                            // clear interrupts

    lgdt [gdt_descriptor];          // load Global Descriptor Table

    mov eax, cr0;                   // switch to protected mode
     or eax, 0x1;                   // set PE ( Protection Enable ) bit in CR0
    mov cr0, eax;                   // CR0 is a Control Register 0

    jmp CODE_SEG:main_x32;          // far jump to 32 bit instructions

[BITS 32]

main_x32:

    mov eax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, eax;
    mov es, eax;
    mov ss, eax;
    movzx esp, sp

    pop edi; LFB address, the value from mode.framebuffer
    mov al, 0x0F;                        the color of the pixel
    mov [edi], al

    jmp $;
```

the vbe theres no problem here as i know, and i did simplify the tables as much as i could:

```
[BITS 16]

VBE:

    .signature db "VBE2";   // must be "VESA" to indicate valid VBE support
    .version resw 1;            // VBE version; high byte is major version, low byte is minor version
    .oem resd 1;            // segment:offset pointer to OEM
    .capabilities resd 1;       // bitfield that describes card capabilities
    .video_modes resd 1;        // segment:offset pointer to list of supported video modes
    .video_memory resw 1;       // amount of video memory in 64KB blocks
    .rest_of_table resb 500 ;... and others values, this block got 512 bytes; and that line is just to simplify the code

    .get_info:

        mov ah, 4Fh;        Super VGA support
        mov al, 00h;        Return Super VGA information
        mov di, VBE;    Pointer to buffer

        int 0x10;

        ret

    .enable:

    call VBE.get_info;
    call mode.get_info;
    call mode.set;

    .draw:

        ;Assume first window is valid 
        mov ax, WORD [es:mode + 08h]
        mov es, ax

        ;Example of how to change the window 
        mov ax, 4f05h
        xor bx, bx
        mov dx, 5       ;This is granularity units
        int 10h

        ;here i can draw a pixel with no problem
        mov edi, [mode.framebuffer]; framebuffer address
        push edi; save edi for pm
        add edi, 180054; pixel address 
        mov al,0x0F;                        the color of the pixel
        mov [edi], al

        ret

mode:

    .attributes resw 1;     // deprecated, only bit 7 should be of interest to you, and it indicates the mode supports a linear frame buffer.
    .window_a resb 1;           // deprecated
    .window_b resb 1;           // deprecated
    .granularity resw 1;        // deprecated; used while calculating bank numbers
    .window_size resw 1;
    .segment_a resw 1;
    .segment_b resw 1;
    .win_func_ptr resd 1;       // deprecated; used to switch banks from protected mode without returning to real mode
    .pitch resw 1;          // number of bytes per horizontal line
    .width resw 1;          // width in pixels
    .height resw 1;         // height in pixels
    .w_char resb 1;         // unused...
    .y_char resb 1;         // ...
    .planes resb 1;
    .bpp resb 1;            // bits per pixel in this mode
    .banks resb 1;          // deprecated; total number of banks in this mode
    .memory_model resb 1;
    .bank_size resb 1;      // deprecated; size of a bank, almost always 64 KB but may be 16 KB...
    .image_pages resb 1;
    .reserved0 resb 1;

    .red_mask resb 1;
    .red_position resb 1;
    .green_mask resb 1;
    .green_position resb 1;
    .blue_mask resb 1;
    .blue_position resb 1;
    .reserved_mask resb 1;
    .reserved_position resb 1;
    .direct_color_attributes resb 1;

    .framebuffer resd 1;        // physical address of the linear frame buffer; write here to draw to the screen
    .off_screen_mem_off resd 1;
    .off_screen_mem_size resw 1;    // size of memory in the framebuffer but not being displayed on the screen
    .reserved1 resb 206;

    .get_info:

        mov ax, 4F01h;        Return mode information
        mov cx, 0x101;[VBE_info.video_modes]; first mode
        mov di, mode;   Pointer to buffer

        int 0x10;

        ret

    .set:

        mov ah, 0
        mov ax, 0x4F02
        mov ebx, [VBE.video_modes]; estore de modes pointer at ebx to can access as a adress
        mov bx, [ebx+8]; 8/2 = 4th mode in the mode array!!!!!!!

        int 0x10

        ret
```

The system dont draw a pixel in protected mode, thus real `edi` its not the same as in protected.
I can't get the saved `edi`, what's the right way to do it?

Comment: You can convert a real mode address that is a segment:offset pair and convert it to a linear address (I assume you aren't using paging in protected mode). To convert a segment:offset to linear address you can take the segment value and shift it left 4 bits (same a multiplying by 16) and then add the offset to that value. So linear_address=(segment<<4)+offset.

Comment: The linear address from that computation can be used in protected mode. If you are going to use protected mode I'd suggest querying VBE for a VESA video mode that uses LFB (linear frame buffer) so that you can access video ram without bank switching etc.

Comment: i think i'm already using LFB cause i can draw in screen using flat/linear adress, i will search, and see how i can access that LFB adress in the protected mode, and thank you for the hints ;)

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/VESA_Video_Modes

Comment: I'm pretty sure the current form of the question is not a [mcve].  Changing to protected mode doesn't affect SS base until you reload the segment register, and if SP=ESP this should Just Work.  Or just choose your ESP correctly if you want to keep using the same stack region, obviously.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I should note that this question is now quite different than the original one I viewed with the OPs new edits. Now it seems to be about potential issues (as you suggest) with changing to protected mode.

Comment: Patrick Sant. Why not just provide a fully functional piece of code that demonstrates the problem including everything. Everything includes a complete boot sector, the GDT, how you enter protected mode etc.

Comment: As Peter says this is likely stack related. On a side note: without seeing the code that enters protected mode - if you never modified EDI when switching into protected mode the value should be the same and you wouldn't even need to save and restore it from the stack.

Comment: ok i will update the post

Comment: As well you seem to `push edi` inside a function and then do a `ret` which I am surprised works at all That would pretty much try to return to the address you pushed on the stack.Are you sure you even get into protected mode?

Comment: yes?, the system crash when i try to use a interrupt( like 10h ) in the protected mode... that means that im in the protected mode right?

Comment: I did update the code with the Michael Petch answer, but still dont getting the `edi` result, and i test the protected mode writing a "!" at the first text mode screen adress( without enable vbe, and putting 0x1234 in edi, and check if in protected mode stills this value, but its not the same ).

Comment: When I recommended `movzx esp, sp` I assumed that SS was zero. You use the value of 0x8000 in SS. You'd have to also add `0x80000` to ESP (0x8000<<4=0x80000) after doing the `movzx`. But that being said your code still pushes EDI inside a function and then does a RET. If you think your code works it is by luck alone. If you want EDI on the stack you might consider moving EDI to ESI in `.draw`, remove the `push` from `.draw` and then push ESI at the start of function `enter_x32` . The reason for moving EDI to ESI is because you modify EDI in `.draw`

Comment: And as I mentioned earlier in a comment if you put the pointer to the video buffer into a register you don't clobber then you don't even need to push and pop from the stack. You don't use ESI in your code. If you `mov esi, edi` in `.draw` and don't change the value of ESI at all, ESI will still have the same value in protected mode.

Comment: You could have also avoided modifying EDI at all in `.draw` if you did `mov [edi+180054], al` rather than adding 180054 ro EDI.

Comment: One last observation. There are very few situations where the code you wrote to draw a pixel in real mode would actually work. One of the few places it would work is QEMU because it doesn't do limit checks when accessing memory. By any chance are you running this in QEMU?

Comment: yup, im using QEMU in the ubuntu 19.10

Comment: I bet if you run it in QEMU with the option `-enable-kvm` it wouldn't even write the pixel in real mode. On real hardware it wouldn't work either. In order to speed things up in QEMU, the emulator doesn't perform certain checks and pretty much allows you to write beyond the 64KiB limit of a real mode segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the title question: The easiest way would be to keep it in a register.

Otherwise, work out the linear address where you store it in memory in real mode, then access the same linear address in protected mode.

(either by simply not modifying `SS` at all so the base stays the same, or more usefully by using a flat memory model with `SS` base = 0 in the GDT and using offset = that linear address.  e.g. by setting ESP to point to the same region of linear / physical memory you were using for a stack in real mode.)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like you: I loaded many sectors of a file to a *specific address in memory* and when switched to Protected mode, suddenly I could not find the information where I loaded. I discover that the mess was being done by a include file that actually did the int 13h to load  sectors by lba. It was without the directives in the top of file, I discovered the painful way that it need to have too:

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]

;... Here the assembly code that
;... loads sectors before
;... switching to protected mode
;... now it works!
```